# underclocking Intel Core i7

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, overheating, underclock

My laptop's CPU is Intel Core i7 Q 720 . Works perfect but the bad side is overheating... Ive already tried to clean laptop and change thermopaste, it doesn't give any results. Is there any programs to make some underclocking or somehow to reduce the temperature. In hard-work mode the temperature under 80, in book reading mode temperature is 60-65...

Ive found some programs like NHC and RMclock but unfortunately they are for core 2 duo processors

At least maybe there are any Intel's programs?

Comment: Did you already check settings in your BIOS to see if they are configurable?

Comment: Yes. it doesn't have any options

Comment: They can run up to 100 degrees celcius... a) you are measuring in celcius, right? and b) possibly consider getting a better fan

Comment: Yes, Celsius. Usually maximal temperature is under 90-95 and then system automatically power off laptop. Maximal temperature that I noticed was 85. I really don't like it, because it really hot and fans are pretty noisy. I had core i5, core i3  before and didn't face with overheating problem. I brought 2 big fans under laptop, it holds temperature under 70-75. But I cant carry big fans everywhere where I am

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, you can not decrease more than 933 MHz, which is the minimum processor frequency (its the minimun multiplier).

The temperature is normal, you should keep in mind that these laptops with this processor model are designed for use on hard surfaces.

I have the same model of processor in my notebook and I have changed the thermal paste for a quality one (Artic Silver) and also wiped the dust and still maintain a similar temperature range (slightly lower) as yours.

Remember also influences the ambiental temperature, for reference my processor goes between 60-80 degrees (min - max workload) celsius at an ambient temperature of 25 to 30 degrees celsius. If this is very annoying you can try a cooling pad to help reducing some degrees.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Phased Lock Loop (PLL) chip on your motherboard that regulates the Front-Side Bus.  All the various utilities, SetFSB being the most widely used, publish a list of supported PLLs.  Get on some relevant web forums and find what PLL your laptop uses.  Once you have that information you can find software utilities for Windows to change clock rates rather easily.

There are other ways to change your CPU frequency, but when reducing temperature is the objective changing the Front-Side Bus is usually the way to go.  It will have the added benefit of increasing battery life.

Under-volting the CPU is likely to have as much if not more effect on CPU temperature than frequency.

Laptops are usually pretty locked down so it is unlikely you have common options for making these changes in your BIOS, but take a look anyway.  This question is pretty much of duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/429249/underclocking-without-bios-option?rq=1).  Infact, there are several questions that answer this pretty thoroughly.