# Will Putting a dust filter over the fan vents damage the fan?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I bought an Intel Hades Canyon as i had a Dell pc of the same form factor earlier and i liked it. While you could open the Dell box to clean the fans which accumulated a lot of dust, the Intel box doesnt provide that access to its fans. After searching for a proper filter which would filter even fine dust i decided to use an AC 'mesh cloth' filter. Any effective filter will also create resistance in the air flow but this answer: [Underclocking without BIOS option](https://superuser.com/questions/429249/underclocking-without-bios-option?rq=1) , in the first paragraph talks about how fans can get damaged if air doesnt flow freely.

So after taping this [filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwYfK.jpg) i checked to see if the cpu temperature at max load changes as i would expect it to change when the fans weren't pushing as much air as they were pushing earlier. There was no difference in the temperatures.

Is there a risk of damaging the fans in the long run? Also these are not the usual 120mm fans but much smaller, like cpu fans.(there are two of them)

Comment: Many cases come with a very fine removable fabric weave over their fan openings ([example](https://www.silverstonetek.com/product_access.php?bno=61&tb=54&area=en)), and that would likely be better than the type of mesh cloth linked to

Comment: Yes, i will definitely buy one of these when im looking for a new setup. But at present im stuck with the nuc

Comment: Ask your mum/girlfriend/wife for an old pair of tights/hose…